# Change the WordPress Permalink Structure for specific post

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdomain

hi I use Polylang for my post languages my post look like these

```
example.com/postname
example.com/es/postname
example.com/fr/postname
```

but now I am trying something new through php redirect code in function php.
I want our posts to look like these with his language posts also look like these.

```
postname.example.com/categoryname
postname.es.example.com/categoryname
postname.fr.example.com/categoryname
```

most important I want only change those URLs which I select not all posts.